# FileNotFoundException for runnable jar with testng

Tags: java, xml, jar, testng

I'm exporting  runnable jar with a main method that reads testng xml and starts execution, however After exporting,  the jar doesn't find xml path, but when I run it through eclipse, it executes fine.

**It is searching for xml on the exported location of jar,instead it should be packed within jar itself.not sure why is so.**

below is the error.
[image]

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is searching for xml on the exported location of jar

No it isn't. Java is looking for that file in the current working directory.

> instead it should be packed within jar itself.not sure why is so.

So it should be accessed via the class-resource API, not via a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: can you please provide something to look for >> accessed via the class-resource API, I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi `Class.getResource()` or `Class.getResourceAsStream()`, or the same methods in `ClassLoader()`: note that they work slightly differently as regards naming.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this problem. You have to place the 'files' in the directory where you have placed the jar file.

Do these changes:

1) Edit your code and write the file's name only where you have put the source location of the file.

2) Then export to .jar file.

3) Put those files (.xml) in the directory where you have placed the .jar file.

It worked for me! I hope it will work for you too.

Comment: You have to place the files in whatever the current working directory is when the program is executed.